# Flex 4 with AIR

Tags: apache-flex, air

Could anyone tell me if it is possible to use the flex 4 framework within an Air app.
Can't seem to find a definitive answer.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use AIR 1.5 is should work, I'm not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: + 1 The Flex 4 framework works with Adobe AIR 1.5, which has not been updated for this release.